# How to regenerate service super-class in Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

So my problem is exactly the same as this guy's here: http://www.pubbs.net/201003/flex/61462-flexcoders-flash-builder-super-class-regeneration.html , but unfortunately, he got no answer.
After initially generating service classes connecting with PHP, I modified the PHP, added new call specifically.
While the Data/Services window successfully made notice of the changes, including new function in the list, the service super-class didn't change whatsoever. Which baffles me, since all super-classes in generated service and valueObject packages contain an annotation like this:

> - This is a generated class and is not intended for modification.  To customize behavior
> - of this service wrapper you may modify the generated sub-class of this class - SomethingService.as.

And also the sub-class contains something about "regeneration of the super-class". So obviously, my goal is to force the mentioned regeneration. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm unclear exactly what you're asking.  Is Flash Builder reverting some changes you made to a file?

Comment: No. I am sorry so much if I didn't make myself clear... Once again: I made changes to the PHP file. Now Flash Builder seems to recognize the change - the Data/Services pane shows the function I added to PHP file. But actionscript service super-class file doesn't change at all. So while it is possible to right-click the function in Data/Services and select "Generate Service Call", the generated service call fails because actionscript class doesn't contain method for the new function. I can obviously add it myself, but I think it is possible *somehow* to force FB to regenerate super-class file..

Comment: I see this questions still gets some views so... It all comes down to opening the service class file **inside Flash Builder**, whether adjacent plugin is installed or not... Then FB gets to notice the change and regenerates super class actionscript file. I'm quite ashamed it took me so long to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem and it was driving me nuts. In my case, I am using an Eclipse plug-in for Team Foundation Server (a source control repository). In TFS, files are kept read-only until you check them out. Usually when something behind the scenes tries to modify a file that I have open, the plug-in will check out the file automatically and let it make the changes. For some reason, it didn't in this case.

So for me, all I had to do was check out the file and it would then be able to regenerate (which translates to making the file writable for the rest of you who might have the same issue).

Answer (score 0):

I find that most code generators work once to generate classes, but do not work well updating them. It's really hard (I've worked on them).

Can you correct your classes by hand?